# Add new cell to a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code to automatically display a new row every time the students need to add a new subject to the table. After entering all the information needed,  the student will have to click on a button that will enable the student to view the grades and gpa of each subject which is supposed to be displayed in a new added cell to the table.

My question is, how can I add a new cell to automatically display the grades and GPA for each subject based on the expected marks entered by the student?

```html
<html>
<title> GPA Calculator </title>

<head>

  <script>
    function addRow(myTable) {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var element1 = document.createElement("input");
      cell1.appendChild(element1);

      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var element2 = document.createElement("input");
      cell2.appendChild(element2);

      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var element2 = document.createElement("input");
      cell3.appendChild(element2);

      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var element3 = document.createElement("input");
      cell4.appendChild(element3);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable" border="1" ; width: "100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Code
      <th>Subject
      <th>Credit
      <th>Expected Mark
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="code1" value="SCJ119"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject1" value="Object-Oriented Programming">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit1" value="4"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark1" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="code2" value="SCK302"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject2" value="Software Engineering"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit2" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark2" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="code3" value="SCO107"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject3" value="Operating System"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit3" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark3" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="code4" value="SSV901"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject4" value="Web Programming"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit4" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark4" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="code5" value="ENG213"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject5" value="Advanced Academic English 
    Skills"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit5" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark5" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="code6" value="QBS221"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject6" value="Structure and Functions of 
    Proteins"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit6" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark6" value=""></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <br><input type="button" value="Add Subject" onclick="addRow('myTable')">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jmargolisvt my question is, how can i add a new cell to AUTOMATICALLY display the grades and gpa for each subject based on the expected marks entered by the student?

Comment: What is "gpa" (I guess grade point average) and how is it calculated? Where are the grades defined?

Comment: @RobG yes, gpa stands for grade point average. It is calculated using this formula :                                                                                               
    **total grade points / total credit hours (in this case, credit)**

Comment: @RobG grade points is the point obtained from each subject. For example: if the grade is an A, the grade point will be 4.00

Answer (score 0):

@RobG I think the only way, to my knowledge, would to use a SQL database and have it be updated via a SQL client. This can be done with software like ISS (built-in to Windows Vista+) or other third-party SQL clients.

Edit: @RobG, I understand that, however, the easiest way to accomplish this is to fetch rows out of a database or even a Microsoft Excel file to use as variables for the grades the student(s) have.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. But this is a javascript assignment, thus I need to apply the javascript, html and css knowledge in order to meet assignment's requirement.

Comment: @RobG, I understand that, however, the easiest way to accomplish this is to fetch rows out of a database or even a Microsoft Excel file to use as variables for the grades the student(s) have.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery below works when the element's value changed;

```
$('.myElements').each(function() {
   var elem = $(this);

   // Save current value of element
   elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

   // Look for changes in the value
   elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
      // If value has changed...
      if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
       // Updated stored value
       elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

       // Do action - You can call javascript function to add cell
       ....
     }
   });
 });
```

When the input value changed you can add one more cell like this(Im in grade);

```
var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
var x = row.insertCell(0);
x.innerHTML = "New cell";
```

Once you have all grades you can calculate the GPA from grade's values as you wish.

I hope this helps you mate.

Comment: There is no jQuery tag, nor is it used in the OP, so your answer should not rely on it. Also, jQuery [*.bind*](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) has long been deprecated (since version 1.7 in November 2011). What elements will *.myElements* select? Are you suggesting adding 6 listeners to each credit and expected mark input?

Comment: You are right, I have not realized missing tag which is jquery but I do not think it is a big deal. Yes I am suggesting that, ofcourse they are better ways to do that but I came up with this solution.